# How do I return my result from this For loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, printing, return

I am creating an exponent function, it is very simple but I cannot get the function to actually print my result when I give users the ability to give inputs. Here is my function which may have issues to begin with.

```
#exponent function
      
bas_num = input("Base Number: ")
pow_num = input("Power: ")

def raise_to_power(bas_num, pow_num):
    result = 1
    for index in range(pow_num):
        result = result * bas_num
    return result
```

as it currently stands I don't get my result back to read.  I can't seem to print it based on user inputs.  I can make it work if I use

```
print(raise_to_power(x, y))
```

but then I am giving the inputs, not the user.

any help appreciated.

EDIT

```
#exponent function

bas_num = int(input("Base Number: "))
pow_num = int(input("Power: "))

def raise_to_power(bas_num, pow_num):
    result = 1
    for index in range(pow_num):
        result = result * bas_num
    return result

print(raise_to_power(bas_num, pow_num))
```

This worked.  Thanks Johnny Mopp

Comment: You need to convert the inputs to numbers: `bas_num = int(input("Base Number: "))`, etc.

Comment: What are `x` and `y`? You need to pass the user inputs to the function: `print(raise_to_power(bas_num, pow_num))`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, These two elements fixed it.  Thank you.  I didn't realize I just re-input those exact same variables in the print function and then it would work.  The x,y were just placeholders to explain that I could force it to work by defining the inputs in my code, but couldn't figure out how to make it work from the user inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corrected version of your code. The input function was moved under the def function, as a result, when the function is called like this: `raise_to_power()` the user will be asked to input bas_num & pow_num.

```
def raise_to_power():
    bas_num = int(input("Base Number: "))
    pow_num = int(input("Power: "))

    result = 1
    for index in range(pow_num):
        result = result * bas_num
    return result
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

If you find this to solve your question then consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: Generally speaking, a function should do one thing (and do it well). I feel the OP's original choice of separating the user input logic and the calculation is better. This makes the function more reusable. For example, if you want to print the squares of the first 10 integers: `for x in range(1, 11): raise_to_power(x, 2)`. You can't do that with your code.